# Read OUTPUT values from SQL stored procedure using PDO and SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm trying to read an OUTPUT value from a SQL stored procedure using PHP, PDO and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SQLSRV), but despite having read several articles on the subject can still not seem to get it working. The stored procedure essentially checks if a record already exists or not, and I want it to return a 1 or a 0 to the PHP depending on what it's found. The value of $retval never gets changed from its originally initialised value of 5, though.

PHP:

```
// Initialise return value variable as an integer type; this should be changed
// by the returned value from SQL

$retval = 5; 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt = $connPDO->prepare('EXEC dbo.EnrollApplicant :applicantID, :retval ');

$stmt->bindParam(':applicantID', $applicantID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
$stmt->bindValue(':retval', $retval, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT);
$stmt->execute();

// Return values to AJAX

echo json_encode(array(
    "RowCount" => $stmt->rowCount(),
    "PDOErrors" => $stmt->errorInfo(),
    "InsertID" => $connPDO->lastInsertID(),
    "applicantID" => $applicantID,
    "retval" => $retval
));
```

SQL:

```
USE [MScPublicDev]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[EnrollApplicant]    Script Date: 11/19/2015 10:31:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[EnrollApplicant]  @APPID INT, @retval int OUTPUT AS

SELECT @APPID

DECLARE @surname AS nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @forename AS nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @studentID AS nvarchar(25)
DECLARE @studentID1 AS nvarchar(100)

SET @surname = (SELECT upper(Surname) FROM Applicant WHERE ID = @APPID )
SET @forename = (SELECT upper(Forename) FROM Applicant WHERE ID = @APPID )
SET @studentID1 = @surname + ', ' + @forename 

SELECT @studentID1
SET @studentID = (SELECT  dbo.GenerateStudentID (@studentID1))
SELECT @studentID AS StudentID

DECLARE @found AS int

SET @found = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student WHERE Surname = @surname and Forename = @forename)

If @found = 0
BEGIN

-- TSQL to Insert Student record from Applicant record details goes here

SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = @studentID

END

@retval = @found

GO
```

Comment: You have some potential logic issues in your procedure. You define @studentID1 as varchar(100) but you make a concatenation of two 50 characters variable and 2 characters in a string literal. You have a number of pieces in here where you could make improvements. I don't know php so I can't speak to that part but I don't see anything in your sql that would prevent the value of retval being changed.

Comment: Well spotted with @studentID1, thanks for that. I didn't write the sproc myself, but am trying to execute it and get the output returned to my php.

Comment: When I am using Output-paramters I have to declare a named parameter-object first, so that I can use it after executing the stored proc and get the ouput-value. I'm not a PHP-Guy but did you try to write $stmt->bindParam(':retval', $retval,.... instead?